# Obtener hora desde un servidor de intenet en Java

Tags: java, netbeans, servidor

quisiera saber como mostrar la hora actual en el país de procedencia desde un servidor que proporcione el servicio de hora en JAVA netbeans

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. Cuál es el código con el que tienes problemas para resolver esta pregunta? Qué pasa cuando lo corres? Qué error encuentras? En qué formato necesitas presentar esa información?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://medium.com/el-acordeon-del-programador/consultando-la-hora-desde-ntp-c18b6c24fe29

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package mx.hash.ejemplontp;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import org.apache.commons.net.ntp.NTPUDPClient;
import org.apache.commons.net.ntp.TimeInfo;

public class NTPService {

    static private final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger("mx.hash.ejemplontp.NTPService");

    public Date getNTPDate() {
        String[] hosts = new String[]{"cronos.cenam.mx", "2.mx.pool.ntp.org"};

        Date fechaRecibida;
        NTPUDPClient cliente = new NTPUDPClient();
        cliente.setDefaultTimeout(5000);
        for (String host : hosts) {
            try {
                LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "Obteniendo fecha desde: {0}", host);
                InetAddress hostAddr = InetAddress.getByName(host);
                TimeInfo fecha = cliente.getTime(hostAddr);
                fechaRecibida = new Date(fecha.getMessage().getTransmitTimeStamp().getTime());
                return fechaRecibida;
                
            } catch (IOException e) {
                LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, "NO SE PUDO CONECTAR AL SERVIDOR {0}", host);
                LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, e.getMessage(), e);
            }
        }
        
        LOGGER.log(Level.WARNING, "No se pudo conectar con servidor, regresando hora local");
        cliente.close();
        return new Date();
    }
}
```

Y nuestra clase main para poder ejecutar el programa

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package mx.hash.ejemplontp;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 *
 * @author david
 */
public class App {
    static private final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger("mx.hash.ejemplontp.App");
    
    static public void main(String[] args){
        NTPService servicioNTP = new NTPService();
        LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "Obteniendo fecha desde el servidor NTP");
        
        Date fecha = servicioNTP.getNTPDate();
        
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Fecha-Hora NTP: " + fecha);
    }    
}
```

Obviamente necesitara agregar las librerias Apache Commons Net a su proyecto para poder compilar y ejecutar este programa, ya que lo haya hecho y el programa haya compilado ejecute el programa y vera una salida como la siguiente.

Comment: gracias amigo .

Comment: ya sabes si te sirvió vota positivo y añade el check de que es correcto para la gente de un futuro

Comment: como hago eso?.

Comment: te sale como este simbolo en gris https://www.shutterstock.com/es/image-vector/vector-illustration-green-check-mark-icon-1713672094 como sale en esta imagen solo le pinchas y listo